Newman CLI returns error "Unable to Get Local Issuer Certificate"
Using Newman CLI to run a Postman collection and I'm getting the following errors:
error: collection could not be loaded
  unable to fetch data from url "https://api.postman.com/collections/<collection URL>"
  unable to get local issuer certificate

Notes:

I'm on a cooperate computer using Zscaler.
The collection points to a publicly available Trello API.
running https://api.postman.com/collections/<collection URL>?apikey=<API key> works in Postman
running curl https://api.postman.com/collections/<collection URL>?apikey=<API key> works in cmd

I'm using the following command to run my collection:
newman run https://api.postman.com/collections/<collection URL>?apikey=<API key>
I've tried:

--insecure
--ssl-extra-ca-certs <Local file path to SSL cert>
--ssl-client-cert <Local file path to SSL cert>
SET NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=<Local file path to SSL cert> & then using NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS after the previous 2 examples instead of the file path (with and without quotes)
npm config set strict-ssl false

Same response each time.
